# Fluent interfaces / extension methods - Turning a flat list into a navigation tree

Tags: c#, tree, extension-methods, fluent, fluent-interface

I currently have an extension Method which converts an IEnumerable of type Tab into a hierarchical collection of TabNodes.

```
// If Tab has no parent its ParentId is -1

public class Tab
{
public int TabId { get; set; }
    public string TabName { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

}

public class TabNode
{
    public TabInfo Tab { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TabNode> ChildNodes { get; set; }
    public int Depth { get; set; }
}
```

For instance, the following would give you a collection of TabNodes who are below a Parent with TabId 32 - the maximum level of depth is 4.

```
IEnumerable<Tab> tabs = GetTabs();

IEnumerable<TabNode> = tabs.AsNavigationHierarchy(32,4);
```

This is confusing and not very friendly for further refinement. What If I'd like to specify a certain Level instead of a ParentID?

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
IEnumerable<TabNode> = tabs.AsNavigationHierarchy().WithStartLevel(2).WithMaxDepth(5)
```

I'm stuck as how to do this elegantly. Can you help me?

This is my current function which is called by my extension methods (based on an article I've found on [www.scip.be](http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET23&Lang=EN)).

```
    private static IEnumerable<TabNode>
      CreateHierarchy(
        IEnumerable<TabInfo> tabs,
        int startTabId,
        int maxDepth,
        int depth)
    {
        IEnumerable<TabInfo> children;


            children = tabs.Where(i => i.ParentId.Equals(startTabId));


        if (children.Count() > 0)
        {
            depth++;

            if ((depth <= maxDepth) || (maxDepth == 0))
            {
                foreach (var childTab in children)
                    yield return
                      new TabNode()
                      {
                          Tab = childTab,
                          ChildNodes =
                            CreateHierarchy(tabs, childTab.TabID, maxDepth, depth),
                          Depth = depth
                      };
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tabs.AsNavigationHeirachy could return a HerirchyQuery object which your next extension methods would then expect. This will let you chain them together.

Comment: +1 But at that point, the rest of the methods would probably actually be members of the HierarchyQuery instead of Extension Methods.

Comment: That's what I thought about initially.. unfortunately my teammates would expect it to return the an IEnumerable<TabNode> with the entire navigation structure if only AsNavigationHierarchy() was called. But actually that's a good idea indeed...

Comment: Yes Chris, I guess it would be some kind of normal builder then

Comment: Concession for your teammates might be that you always have to end with .Execute() [or some other method] that actually executes the query and returns the IEnumerable<TabNode>.

Comment: Return an object which Implements IEnumerable<TabNode> but also has the limits to limit the output.

Comment: I'm actually Implementing IEnumerable<Tab> now... thanks for the input